# docbook wysiwyg editor for the web

Tags: editor, docbook

Is there any ready-to-go docbook editor for web applications out there?
I'm thinking of something like FCKeditor or TinyMCE that returns a docbook xml code back to the web application. I am aware that FCKeditor is customizable to do this, but I have not heard of anyone who did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the Xopus web based XML editor does the trick?
http://xopus.com/xopus-web-based-wysiwyg-xml-editor.html
It has support for Dita and Docbook.

Comment: Are there any otheres that actually have a demo/free mode for editing a Docbook file? Xopus does not.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for an online docbook IDE or an editor that automates a lot of the XML rigmarole associated with the docbook format.

You could try the oXygen editor http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/docbook_editor.html . Their trial is 30 days to see if you like it.

Hopefully that gives you some new google terms as well, but that is all I have.

(If, in addition to a good tool for what you need, you find a nice graphical validator. I would love to see something that works better for my work flow than command line jing.)

Answer (score 1):

Docbook is one of the file formats supported for single-source editing in Open/ Libreoffice.

Note that there can be no such thing as a WYSIWYG editor for a presentation-neutral document representation: to be WYSIWYG, things like page dimensions and margins need to be fixed.